# Finding maximum (elementary calculus problem)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

The displacement of a particle from an origin is given by the following function

$s(t) = t^2 \cos t + 2t \sin t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 5$.

The problem is to find the maximum distance of the particle from 0.

So everyone knows how it goes, I need to find derivative

$s'(t) = 2t \cos t - t^2 \sin t + 2 \sin t + 2t\cos t$ and then solve $s'(t) = 0$ and so on. The reason I got here with this problem is that I could't solve $s'(t) = 0$. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Third term of $s'(t)$ should be $2\text{sin}(t)$, not $2\text{cos}(t)$.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, I changed it in the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the identities for $\text{sin}(A+B)$, $\text{cos}(A+B)$ etc. Of course you can simplify the first and last terms to get $4t\text{cos}t$

Comment: Yes, I am actually a grad student who stuck with this for some reason so you can suggest to use any reasonable results. How do you suggest to use sin(a+b) and such?

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor Are you actually able to get an "exact" solution using your suggestion? When these products between polynomials and trigonometric functions occur, it is very unusual that a solution can be obtained without the use of special functions. The numerical solution is $t = 3.99444$, with the corresponding distance being aprox. $16.5131$

Comment: @PierreCarre I agree that it looks like it doesn't have an exact solution. Given the lack of context, I provisionally assumed that it was a standard textbook question for which an exact solution can be obtained.

Comment: @Vladislav How did you come across this problem?

Comment: The problem is from an exam similar to SAT so I think there should be an exact solution.  So either I misunderstood the problem or there is a mistake.

Comment: Is this a multiple-choice question?  It looks to me like you can get fairly close to the exact answer by considering   symmetrical "envelopes" like $ \ 2 \pm x^2 \ $ to get an idea of how the oscillations behave (the function is even).  Then using $ \ t \ = \ \frac{5 \pi}{4} \ \sim \ 4 \ \ $ puts you in the vicinity (you can produce an estimate like $ \ -12 \sqrt2 \ \ ) \ . $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum/minimum value of $s(t)=t^2\cos t + 2t \sin t$ in the interval $[0,5]$ can occur at the endpoints or at points in $(0,5)$ where $s'(t) = 0$. So, the answer requires that you are able to solve the equation
$$
4 t \cos (t)-\left(t^2-2\right) \sin t =0
$$

There are actually two solutions in $(0,5)$, with the maximum distance being attained for $t \approx 3.9944$.

The equation does not seem to be solvable using elementary functions. Is a numerical solution sufficient for your purposes? What tools are you allowed to use?

Comment: I don’t think that numerical are allowed. It’s from an exam similar to SAT (I was teaching that kind of stuff and needed to explain this problem but got stuck while doing so). May be there is a mistake in the problemsheet.

Comment: What is the exact original question?

Comment: I copied it in my question (omitting the info that distance in in santimeters and time in seconds).